# Qt, Getting the text when QPainter::drawText() is called

Tags: qt, redirect, intercept, drawtext

I have a QPainter object and would like to obtain the string that is drawn whenever QPainter::drawText is called, as I would if I could connect a slot to that signal (which doesn't exist, so I can't). 
What would be the best way to do this? I have read some stuff about redirecting the drawText method to a custom one using the setProperty method, and passing it a pointer to drawText, but I've never tried it, and it seems like overkill to me..
Anyone have a better idea about how to obtain the String of text that is drawn by drawText?

Edit: It would also be ok if instead of getting the text form the painter, we get it from the PaintEngine

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only reliable way is to subclass QPainter, reimplement the drawText() method and add some debug text in your own class. I doubt QPainter has any facilities to capture a signal or something, since most of the drawing methods are speed critical.

Comment: Agreed. You'd have to derive from QPainter and override drawText.